# Divide count by count with InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to calculate the percentage of values within a threshold.

How would do something like this with InfluxDB?

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM "durations"  WHERE "duration" < 500
)
/
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM "durations"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible in plain InfluxQL.

You have to have every data point that belongs to particular dimension *(and the range value belongs to IS a sort of a dimension, which is identified by tags)* explicitly in your measurement.

See examples of something alike (without aggregation, though) [there](http://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/guides/calculating_percentages/) (pay attention how sample dataset looks like).

Although, what you're asking for could be done in Kapacitor (most likely, with Join and/or Union nodes, I guess).